# Nokia 8 does not work as USB modem in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, usb-modem

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

When I plug Honor 8 phone via USB to my PC and switch it to USB modem mode, I see a notification about a new network immediately.

I can see the following in `dmesg` output:

```
[  571.822148] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  571.951144] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1039
[  571.951154] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[  571.951160] usb 1-3: Product: PLK-L01
[  571.951166] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  571.951171] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: H8WDU15930015927
[  571.976176] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[  571.978838] rndis_host 1-3:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, RNDIS device, 9a:7a:13:2b:54:bb
[  571.978964] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[  571.982937] rndis_host 1-3:1.0 enp0s20f0u3: renamed from usb0
[  572.005541] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20f0u3: link is not ready
```

So it actually gets picked up by the system as a network device (sorry for the term, it's probably wrong, but I guess you understand what I mean).

But when I plug Nokia 8 phone and switch it to USB modem mode, nothing happens. No network appears. Here is what appears in `dmesg` output:

```
[  682.667386] usb 1-14: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  682.853794] usb 1-14: New USB device found, idVendor=0489, idProduct=c022
[  682.853803] usb 1-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  682.853809] usb 1-14: Product: Nokia 8
[  682.853814] usb 1-14: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[  682.853819] usb 1-14: SerialNumber: NB1GAD1772507594
```

So the device is recognized, but no network is added.

I checked this phone on the same PC (via the same USB port) on Windows 10, there everything works fine: I get a notification about a new network, and I can open web pages using the new network. So the hardware seems to be ok.

I also tried kernel 4.10 to no avail.

Is this Ubuntu inability to use Nokia 8 as a USB modem caused by a lack of drivers?
Is it possible to add such a driver, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that you just need to upgrade your kernel to make Nokia 8 work as a USB modem. I don't know the exact minimal kernel version that supports it, but it does not work in 4.10 and it does work in 4.15 and 4.18.

In Ubuntu 16.04, it is enough to switch to HWE (HardWare Enablement) kernel which is currently 4.15:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
```

And reboot.

Or you could upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 where the kernel version is 4.18.

Newer versions would probably work as well, but I only consider LTS ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm!